# Jquery scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a place for posting questions regarding the code issues but please can anyone help me out with this I need a scrolling jQuery effect like when we are on that section like if portfolio section is active then the content start scrolling automatically like in this website section number 4 what jQuery I have to use at http://stampsy.com. Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Even if I wanted to help I don't understand your question.

Comment: please review http://stampsy.com section 4 there is a scroling portfolio i need to create like this

Comment: So basically you're asking: "Please have a look at that website and build it for me". Now, this isn't a Gimme The Codez site in the first place, but please have at least the dignity to provide a proper description of *what* you want, instead of letting us figure that out too.

Comment: oppps in hurry I wrote wrong line incorrect sorry about this mistake and i dont know how do i edit my post

Comment: please review stampsy.com section 4 there is a scroling portfolio i need to create like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question but I think you want the picture slide effect?

If so, I would recommend using the bootstrap Carousel, should give you what you need.

EDIT:

For the section number 4 just use the CSS scroll effects.

Comment: the effect I am asking for is like on stampsy.com section no 4 it is not a bootstrap corusel I beleive

Comment: Use CSS, it has scroll effects for things like that.

Comment: marquee effect will work ? it's like marquee effect

Comment: Yeah, a Marquee effect should do it